# How to get audio and images in a single session using AVFoundation framework iPhone?

Tags: iphone, avfoundation

My requirement is, store video with audio in server which taking from iPhone camera, for that I am using AVFoundation Framework, converting incoming buffer(CMSampleBufferref) to images then I don't know how to get audio from the same session.

Comment: were u able to find out the solution. I m after the same case. If u were able to do that please show me hpw to do that.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367717/create-an-application-that-creates-a-video-from-iphone-screen-and-add-audio-from