# Create an application that creates a video from iphone screen and add audio from headphones / audio input

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, avfoundation

I m trying to create a tutorial video from ipad screen [as done in this application (ShowME)](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/showme-interactive-whiteboard/id445066279?mt=8) Using AVAssetWriter I am able to capture a video of the screen.

I tried using AVCaptureDevice, but Its not working. I dont know what is going wrong. 
I learned capturing video from iphone screen from this [link - A very nice turorial.](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673)
But it does not captures any audio along with screen video. So I gave a try like this:

```
 -(void)setUpMike{
    NSError* error = nil;
// Setup the audio input
AVCaptureDevice *audioDevice     = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio];
AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioDevice error:&error ];     
// Setup the audio output
_audioOutput = [[AVCaptureAudioDataOutput alloc] init];

// Create the session
_capSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

[_capSession addInput:audioInput];

[_capSession addOutput:_audioOutput];

_capSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetLow;     

// Setup the queue
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("MyQueue", NULL);
//    [_videoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];
[_audioOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];
dispatch_release(queue);
}
```

I added the delegate method

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

This is never called. Hope any one can help me around for this.
I have never used AVFoundation for video and audio purpose, So may be a newbie Question. 
I read other posts relating this and found that the are merging audio with video. I think we can go through this way. Please inform me if this is not possible.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally recorder audio as different file and then merged them to create a video with audio and video. I used AVMutableComposition to create a final video. If any one know how to record it with assets as you are creating video with AVAssetWriter, then please help me out. I might change my code :)

Comment: I think you mean AVMutableComposition

Comment: Hey we are trying same approach with separate video and audio file but no luck, the camera video gets stuck when I start recording the audio. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @PGU - You probably solved it now, but I am guessing it is a threading issue. Too many executions scheduled on the main thread. Do file IO asynchronously if you need to run things in real time on the main thread.

Comment: @DevineDesert -First of all thanks for your answer , I've been working on same kind of app (screen recording feature)my Video could not saved on real device ,I can get same output sample in my Documents Directory in Default path  /var/mobile/Applications/8E4FFF35-267D-4B46-9A4B-D7D1BC361F72/Documents/foo.mp4 using simulator

Comment: @DevineDesert Yeah but I could not able to save that video on real device. I'm using same AVAssetWriter Class

Comment: Any chance you guys have any code to share? This would be a great thing to post to github, especially if it expands on the example linked in the original post